# HTML 5 Drag and Drop event data(e.dataTransfer) is coming undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a file uploader using HTML 5 drag and drop. The problem is when an object is dropped on the target div and drop event is triggered the Data in the event is undefined.
The value of event.dataTransfer is Undefined.

```
function uploader(elementSelector) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var element = $(elementSelector);
        dropBox(element);
    })

    function dropBox(DivSelector) {
        $(DivSelector)
            .css({
                'min-width': '300px',
                'max-width': '300px',
                'min-height': '300px',
                'background-color': 'grey'
            })
            .on('drop', function(e) {
                console.log(e);
                dropHandler(e);
            })
            .on('dragover', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
    }

    function dropHandler(ev) {
        alert("Dropped");
        ev.preventDefault();
        // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
        var dt = ev.dataTransfer;
        if (dt.items) {
            // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.items.length; i++) {
                if (dt.items[i].kind == "file") {
                    var f = dt.items[i].getAsFile();
                    console.log("... file[" + i + "].name = " + f.name);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.files.length; i++) {
                console.log("... file[" + i + "].name = " + dt.files[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ckckchoudhary/v2k15ms9/#&togetherjs=AcNjl0V2Rg

Comment: remove your alert and you should be good. Ah you also need to get the dataTransfer from the `ev.originalEvent` since you're dealing with jQuery. https://jsfiddle.net/v2k15ms9/2/